# rails 3 auto complete (prototypejs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, prototypejs

I'm looking for a good auto complete plugin for rails3, based on prototype.

The plugin of dhh should be the right one, but a bit old (last commit in 2007)

do you have any good experience with one of the 68 fork with rails 3? ([rails/auto_complete/network](https://github.com/rails/auto_complete/network))

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First result on google and *incredibly* easy to get up and running. May require a bit of DIY and elbow grease but I found it to be minimally invasive...

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/

Comment: Apologies - read over that question maybe a little too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

**Rails3-jquery-autocomplete** is the best plugin to date :

https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

It has a good documentation on github, it can get you up & running in a few minutes.

Comment: he was looking for a **prototype** plugin, not jquery.